# get drive period and stop period from gps Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table which contains gps data.
It saves a record every 30 Seconds
A record contains `speed` (float), `CurrTime` (datetime) and `CarID` (int)

How can I get (for each car and day) those values :

- total drive period
- total stop period

> Stop means its `speed must be <5 for continous 15 minutes`

### For example :

> car1 on 7/7/2017
>
> - stopped for 10 Hours
> - drive for 14 hours

## Table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_Tracking](
[id] [int]  ,
[IMEI] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[TrackTime] [datetime] NULL,
[CurrTime] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_T_Tracking_CurrTime]  DEFAULT (getutcdate()),
[Longitude] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Lattitude] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[speed] [float] NULL,
[SafeAreaID] [int] NULL,
[GeoFenceID] [int] NULL,
[CarID] [int] NULL,
[Country] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[City] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Area] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Street] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[FullAddress] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
[Distance] [float] NULL  )
```

This [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb633d/1) is auto-populated with table definition and some data examples

(Parking)
       To ignore trafic stops

### Data Examples

[image]

## Expected Data

```
CarName    Date        DrivePeriod    StopPeriod
Car1        7/7/2017      16              8
Car2        7/7/2017       14             10
car3        7/7/2017       12             12
car1        6/7/2017        15             9
```

## My try

```
SELECT carid
,sum( LAG( TrackTime, 1, Null) OVER (PARTITION BY carid ORDER BY carid)- TrackTime) 
FROM T_Tracking 
group by carid
```

### Error encountered

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Column 'T_Tracking.TrackTime' is
>   invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 4109, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another
>   windowed function or aggregate.

Try 2

```
      SELECT 
    carid
  , TrackTime
  , LAG( TrackTime, 1, Null) OVER (PARTITION BY  carid  ORDER BY carid) as trackold
  , CONVERT(date, TrackTime) as TrackDay
  , speed,DATEDIFF(minute, LAG( TrackTime, 1, Null) OVER (PARTITION BY  carid  ORDER BY carid),TrackTime)
FROM T_Tracking
```

result
[image]

the problem here when the lag record on another day it get wrong subtarction
i need to put a contition to be in the same day

Comment: The sql fiddle page is just continuously loading....is there a ton of data or something? Can you post the sample data here? In addition to the sample data knowing what you expect for output would be very helpful. And a little bit of explanation of the output would go a long way.

Comment: What did you try until now ? Also please make sure you improve your questions' formatting a little.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you on ? And what compatibility setting is the database ?

Comment: Sql servr 2014 what do you mean by compatiblity settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a CTE that calculates for each column if it is considered as stopped or not
+ a `GROUP BY YEAR(CurrTime), MONTH(CurrTime), DAY(CurrTime), CarId, Stopped` will do the job.

Then you only have to `SUM()` the amount of time between a current record time
and its `LAG()` value and it's done.

[WITH CTE "Common Table Expression"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) (starting with SQL Server 2008)
[GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql) (starting with SQL Server 2008)
[SUM Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql) (starting with SQL Server 2008)
[LAG Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) (starting with SQL Server 2012)

Easy to tell, that if you are under SQL Server 2008 this will be very tricky to achieve.

If you are under SQL Server 2012 you can replace the LAG function with a sub-select for example.

### Example of query

```
WITH Stopped
    AS  
    ( CTE_query_definition )  
SELECT 
YEAR(CurrTime)
,MONTH(CurrTime)
,DAY(CurrTime)
,CarID
,Stopped
,SUM(CurrTime - LAG(CurrTime) OVER ( order_by_clause ))
FROM [dbo].[T_Tracking]
GROUP BY YEAR(CurrTime),MONTH(CurrTime),DAY(CurrTime),CarID,Stopped
```

Then you just have to replace `( CTE_query_definition)` and `order_by_clause` to achieve your goal

Comment: Sql server 2014

Comment: can you give more details how to get the period out from the time i.e subtract record time from previous time and where this result go

Comment: Maybe you should give a try with all the documentation I gave and stuff. You did not managed to give us what you tried already I don't get why I should do all the job

Comment: OK this is my Query SELECT carid,
   sum( LAG( TrackTime, 1, Null) OVER (PARTITION BY  carid  ORDER BY carid)- TrackTime) 
  FROM T_Tracking
  group by carid but  it is not Working Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'T_Tracking.TrackTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 4109, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate. i can't group by tracktime

Comment: Your query would return (if it worked) for each car ID the number of hours since the first time it started to log its entries.

Comment: Please See Edit

Comment: Please watch my answer, im done reading what's written here. You make no effort

Comment: you did not see the edit your ery work but in the case in the edit the crrent record date is 16-7 the lag record date 14-7 the subtract will give wrong data my question in this case how to make sure that the current record and its lag in the same day ?